# Al refrescar la pagina se vuelven a enviar los datos a la base de datos

Tags: php, pdo

tengo un bug cuando envío mis datos desde el navegador mediante un  `input` y un `button` y posteriormente al refrescar se reenvía el formulario de nuevo.

El mismo código esta en el `index`

```
<?php
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  $post = isset($_POST['input-post']) ? $_POST['input-post'] : "null";
  $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=web',"root","");
  $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $statement = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO post(usuario, cuerpo,time_date_post) VALUES (:username,:post,:time_date_post)");
  $statement->bindParam(':username', $user);
  $statement->bindParam(':post', $post);
  $statement->bindParam(':time_date_post', $date);
  $statement->execute();
}
?>
<form class="" action="" method="post">
  <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
    <div class="input-group-prepend" style="display:none;">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">@</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="input-post" class="form-control" placeholder="¿Que estas pensando?" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping">
  </div>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Compartir</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una técnica que yo utilizo para evitar ese problema, es con una variable de sesión que indica a la función de modificar la base de datos que ya se hizo una inserción en ella.

```
<?php
session_start();
function insertar_db() {
    if($_SESSION['inserted_db'] == TRUE) {
        echo '<p>[Error] El valor ya fue registrado</p>'.PHP_EOL;
        return;
    }
    $query = "INSERT INTO ...";
    /* resto del codigo de insersion */
    $_SESSION['inserted_db'] = TRUE; // Se indica que la insersión fue correcta
}

function mostrar_formulario() {
    $_SESSION['inserted_db'] = FALSE; // Resetea la variable para que permita insertar otra vez
    ?>
    <form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name=...>
    /* resto de los inputs */
    </form>
    <?php
}

// Inicia aqui
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    insertar_db();
} else {
    mostrar_formulario();
}
```

En tu caso, tienes todo en un mismo código sin funciones. Sin embargo se podría adaptar algo parecido.
Se me ocurre que se podría almacenar un valor "aleatorio" en una variable de sesión. Propondría que ese valor sea *timestamp*, el cual se envía por POST a través de un campo de formulario *hidden*.

Si el valor de `$_SESSION['timestamp']` actual es igual `$tmstamp`, quiere decir que el usuario introdujo los datos correctamente por el formulario. En caso contrario, si el usuario actualiza o presiona F5, se va a volver a recibir el mismo `$tmstamp` anterior, pero `$_SESSION['timestamp']` va a tener un valor diferente más reciente.

```
<?php
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $post = isset($_POST['input-post']) ? $_POST['input-post'] : "null";
    $tmstamp = $_POST['tmstamp'];
    if($tmstamp == $_SESSION['timestamp']) {
        $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=web',"root","");
        $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $statement = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO post(usuario, cuerpo,time_date_post) VALUES (:username,:post,:time_date_post)");
        $statement->bindParam(':username', $user);
        $statement->bindParam(':post', $post);
        $statement->bindParam(':time_date_post', $date);
        $statement->execute();
    } else {
        echo '<p>[Error] El valor ya fue registrado</p>'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
$_SESSION['timestamp'] = strtotime("now"); // Actualiza esta variable
?>

<form class="" action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="tmstamp" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['timestamp']; ?>">
<div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
  <div class="input-group-prepend" style="display:none;">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">@</span>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="input-post" class="form-control" placeholder="¿Que estas pensando?" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping">
</div>
<br>
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Compartir</button>
</form>
```

Comment: me lanza error 500

Comment: El error está en tu código, ya sea en la conexión a la BD, o antes, o después del código que has publicado acá. Si copias el mismo código que puse, comentas la linea `$user = $_SESSION['user'];` y también comentas las 7 líneas que están debajo del `if($tmstamp == $_SESSION['timestamp'])`, el código funciona perfectamente. Obviamente sin hacer las inserciones, pero el comportamiento es el deseado.

Answer (score 1):

Agrega `header` para redirecionar

```
<?php
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  $post = isset($_POST['input-post']) ? $_POST['input-post'] : "null";
  $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=web',"root","");
  $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  $statement = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO post(usuario, cuerpo,time_date_post) VALUES (:username,:post,:time_date_post)");
  $statement->bindParam(':username', $user);
  $statement->bindParam(':post', $post);
  $statement->bindParam(':time_date_post', $date);
  $statement->execute();
  header("Location: index.php"); /*redireciona*/
}
?>
```

Comment: Pero tanto el form como el código están en el mismo archivo y al refrescar el mismo se envía de nuevo, no uso el Action del form

Answer (score 0):

Debes poner el código `PHP` en un archivo diferente y usar el `action`. Posteriormente usar una redirección después de hacer el envío `header("Location: index.php");` o puedes cambiar el comportamiento de esta línea:

`$post = isset($_POST['input-post']) ? $_POST['input-post'] : "null";`

Ya que le estás diciendo que si `input-post` no está seteado, igual envíe el formulario con ese campo vacío... ***con el valor `"null"`***

Al estar ambos códigos en el mismo archivo `index`, se produce el envío automático del formulario.

Otra opción *aunque no estoy 100% seguro de que funcione y no es la manera mas recomendable de hacerlo en tu caso* es agregar el atributo `required` a tu `input`.

`<input type="text" name="input-post" class="form-control" placeholder="¿Que estas pensando?" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping" required>` de esta manera el formulario no se envía si el campo está vacío.